# How to append to an array with a dynamic variable name?

Tags: bash, array

```
section_example=(one two three)
name=example; section_$name+=(four)

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `four'
```

Section names are unknown beforehand. `eval` and `declare -a` output the same error. The only approach I see is to declare an associative array with section names and values.

Comment: Using an associative array would be a great idea for data keyed by a string. Except that Bash doesn't support nested data structures, so you can't do that...

Comment: So the solution is not to use bash for something it's not suited for, but to use a language that does support nested data structures.  Perl, for example - see the man pages for `perldata`, `perldsc`, `perllol`, `perlref`, and `perlreftut`.  Perl can do everything that awk, sed, tr, and bash can do and a lot more besides.  Not every problem is a nail, sometimes you have to put down that hammer you already know and look in the toolbox for a more appropriate tool, even if it takes some effort to learn how to use it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the `eval`ed command fail if double quoted? Like

```
name=example; eval "section_$name+=(six)"
echo "${section_example[@]}"
one two three four five six
```

Recent `bash`es offer "nameref" variables. `man bash`:

> A  variable can be assigned the nameref attribute using the -n option to the declare or local builtin commands (see the descriptions of declare and local below) to create a nameref, or a reference to another variable.  This allows variables to be manipulated indirectly...

Try

```
> declare -n NamRef=section_$name
> NamRef+=(four)
> echo "${NamRef[@]}"
one two three four
> echo "${section_example[@]}"
one two three four
```

Comment: If this is inside a function, the flag should be probably "-gn" to work on a global variable